# NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder не содержит определения PasswordAsSecureString

Tags: c#, npgsql

Создаю консольное приложение на C# для работы с БД PostgreSQL с помощью пакета Npgsql. Пароль вводится из консоли и передаётся в конструктор класса Database в виде SecureString из встроенной библиотеки System.Security.

В классе Database создаётся экземпляр класса NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder у которого должно быть свойство PasswordAsSecureString, но компилятор говорит, что его нет.

```
using Npgsql;
using System.Security;

    // Класс для работы с базой данных
    class Database : IDisposable
    {
        // Поле для хранения объекта подключения
        private NpgsqlConnection conn;

        // Конструктор класса, который принимает параметры подключения
        public Database(string host, int port, string username, SecureString password, string database)
        {
            // Создаем объект NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder с параметрами подключения
            NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.Host = host; // адрес сервера
            builder.Port = port; // порт сервера
            builder.Database = database; // имя базы данных
            builder.Username = username; // имя пользователя
            builder.PasswordAsSecureString = password; // пароль в виде SecureString

            // Создаем объект подключения
            conn = new NpgsqlConnection(builder);
            conn.Open();
        }
    }
```

Файл проекта

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="7.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Текст ошибки

`Серьезность    Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления Ошибка  CS1061  "NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder" не содержит определения "PasswordAsSecureString", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "PasswordAsSecureString", принимающий тип "NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).  TestDB  D:\!!!E\CSharp\TestDB\TestDB\Database.cs    21  Активные`

(Код по большей части сгенерирован нейросетью. Если такого свойства не существует, то хотелось бы узнать об альтернативных решениях данной проблемы.)

Comment: Класс `SecureString` устарел и более не используется в .NET https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md

Comment: Загляните в документацию, там все есть https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder_Password